# Stolen Guinea-Bissau Passport with Schengen Visa

Tags: passports, guinea-bissau-citizen

I’m in a really difficult position. My wallet got robbed in the UK with all my documents, my Guinea-Bissau passport and Visa, and my UK Biometric Residence Permit.

I’m currently living in UK and my passport was stolen here.

The problem is that a passport replacement can only be issued in Portugal or France. Do you have any idea on how I can do that without any papers?

I have asked for a replacement BRP but I’m not sure about my Visa if I can ask for any replacement which is still 3 months valid (btw I asked for a Schengen Visa so I could enter to Portugal as I was due to travel on 17/12/18)

Comment: I think your best option is to call the embassy in Paris or Lisbon and ask for assistance. They may have an option to replace your passport by mail, or may be able to have a passport issued through another embassy in London. Regarding the Schengen visa, I believe you'll have to reapply for one explaining the circumstances, so it should be relatively quick, but definitely not in time to travel on monday. You'll most probably have to cancel that trip :-(

Comment: you should report that to the police and with that go to immigration, after that contact the embassy of Guinea Bissau and ask if they have cooperation embassies in UK that can help you to get a new passport.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it is very important to report your stolen passport to the police, this can be done using [this service](https://www.reportmyloss.com/uk/#) which is accredited by UK police. The UK Government [advises all stolen passports to be reported](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/report-your-lost-or-stolen-passport).

Next, you need to call the embassy in Paris or Lisbon and explain the situation as to replace your BRP you need a passport.

They might let you replace it at an embassy in London or offer an alternative solution like mentioned in the comments to replace it by mail, the only way to get a definite answer as to what to do is by contacting them.

Next, you need to report your BRP as stolen and apply for a replacement (if you don't do this you could face a fine), as mentioned on the [GOV website](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/lost-stolen-damaged):

> ## If you’re in the UK
>
> If your lost or stolen BRP was valid for 3 months or more, [report it](https://www.biometric-residence-permit.service.gov.uk/lost-stolen/where) and [apply for a replacement](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/biometric-residence-permit-replacement-service). You must do this within 3 months of losing it.
>
> **You can be fined up to £1,000 and made to leave the UK if you do not apply for a replacement within 3 months.**

If it will expire in the next 3 months according to the [GOV website](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/lost-stolen-damaged) you need to:

> **If your BRP was valid for 3 months or less, you must do one of the following:**
>
> - [report it as lost or stolen](https://www.biometric-residence-permit.service.gov.uk/lost-stolen/where) if you do not intend to remain in the UK after its expiry date
> - [apply for a replacement](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/biometric-residence-permit-replacement-service) if you plan to leave and re-enter the UK within 3 months of its expiry date
> - apply to extend your visa if you want to stay in the UK after its expiry date - if granted, you’ll automatically get a new BRP